# Prisma findMany type for tanstack react table usage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma, tanstack-table

I want to make a table (using tanstack table) with data fetched with Prisma.findMany. Let's say I have a User model:

```js
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  age String
  email String
}
```

Now In my page component I use (for pagination):

```js
const users = await prisma.user.findMany({skip: 0, take: 10})
```

Then I need to create columnDefs:

```js
export const userColumnDefs: ColumnDef<WHAT_HERE>[] = [
  {
    accessorKey: "id",
    header: "ID",
    enableHiding: false,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "User Name",
    accessorFn: (user: WHAT_HERE) => user.name,
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button onClick={() => column.toggleSorting()}>
          <span className="text-xs">User Name</span>
        </Button>
      );
    },
    enableHiding: false,
  },
  ...and more
]
```

My question is what type I can use for that case? I want extract columnDefs to another file so can't really do `typeof users`

I couldn't really find any proper solution so thanks for every comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prisma generate` command generates types for every table at `"@prisma/client"`;

```
import { type User } from "@prisma/client";

export const userColumnDefs: ColumnDef<User>[] = [
  {
    accessorKey: "User Name",
    accessorFn: (user) => user.name,
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button onClick={() => column.toggleSorting()}>
          <span className="text-xs">User Name</span>
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
]
```